# Security Descriptor for process only

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

I am calling CreateDesktop and the last parameter of CreateDesktop points to a SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES structure. I was wondering how could I restrict access to the desktop for everyone else, but NOT THE CURRENT PROCESS. Is there a way to do that for a security descriptor? Does the `RawSecurityDescriptor` class in .NET Work?

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: No, you cannot set the limitation of Security Descriptor for current process only but you can set for the user specified.

`SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` contains a [`SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/security-descriptors), which specifies the access rights allowed or denied to particular users or groups by `DACL`. Unless you create a new user or group for running the current process, this will not restrict other processes under the same user or group.

To Create a Security Descriptor to allow a specified user, you could refer to the following document:

[Creating a Security Descriptor for a New Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/creating-a-security-descriptor-for-a-new-object-in-c--)